# Youtube API v3 Return Lat/Lng

Tags: youtube-api

I can search lat/long with YouTube v3 successfully,

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet,id&maxResults=50&type=video& videoType=any&key=foobar&location=40.7127,74.0059&locationRadius=100km
```

However, the response doesnt give me the individual videos lat/lng in the results.

The [API doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) says:

> The part parameter specifies a comma-separated list of one or more
>   search resource properties that the API response will include. Set the
>   parameter value to snippet.

I cannot find any other search resource properties besides id and snippet in Search:list. 
(Why would the API include that first sentence if there are only 2 options?) I digress.

Question-
Is there any way that I can retrieve YT videos lat/long based on lat/long search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have lat/long parameters of the videos you own or manage. But due to privacy reasons (been able to locate people from their uploads.) you won't be able to get specific geolocations of other people's uploads.